# Installing Microsoft GSL: Guideline Support Library on Windows - sigemptyset not declared

Tags: c++, git, cmake, cygwin

I'm trying to install the MS Guideline Library and upon building the library, I get this error: `sigemptyset was not declared in this scope` from `tests/unittest-cpp/UnitTest++/Posix/SignalTranslator.cpp`.

I am using Cygwin and attempting to follow the installation instructions here: https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL.git

I believe that it has something to do with it detecting me on a Linux platform hence the `Posix` folder, is there something that I need to do in Cygwin to set my platform?

Thanks,

Comment: GSL is a header only library, what you are trying to build is its unittest, which is used for its development only. In order to do that unittest, you need to fetch its unittest dependency by `git submodule update --init`

Comment: You can go direct to [this section](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL#using-the-libraries) to know how to use it

Comment: Wherever better for you

Comment: ok, so i don't see a single GSL header file, is it in the repo somewhere? or do i just include the entire GSL folder into my project src tree? I am just using cmake/make to compiler my programs do I don't have any IDE. https://gyazo.com/4ddab6c05621b03795cfdf2521b66241

Comment: `#include <gsl/gsl>` read that manual